# Can you create two things that are exactly the same?

Tags: terminology

Is it possible to create two objects that are the same on the molecular level?

By two objects, I mean two different objects that have the same label.

For example, can you create two different breads that have the same molecular structure? How do we know that they don't?

Are all iPhones 8 structured molecularly the same?

What about drinks?

Let's say someone orders a sprite. Are any other sprites the same in regards to the molecular structure?

Comment: What turns philosophically on the answer? Friendly question ;)-

Comment: Does "exactly the same" only include their internal structure, or does it also include their relationship to other external things, including spatial relationships to other things?

Comment: Depends on the meaning of "can" and "exactly". It is not logically impossible, but random fluctuations make it physically impossible unless by "things" one means two [identical quantum particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles) that are indistinguishable for theoretical reasons, or "exactly" is used in a loose sense of close enough for practical purposes.

Comment: For two things being exactly equal, shouldn't they share the same space? In that case, two (physical) objects could never be equal.

Comment: token vs type identity i guess @perencia see this op https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity/

Comment: Question: Do you consider, say, two water molecules the same? All water molecules are chemically identical, consisting of two H's and one O bound a certain way (I'm no chemist) but are they "the same?" They're not the same molecule. Are they identical enough for your purposes?

Answer (score 3):

From a mathematical perspective we often define equality up to "isomorphism" or "homeomorphism" or some "morphism-ism". These just mean that all objects that are resident in the same Equivalence class are indistinguishable under a certain "lense" unique to each class. In fact the arithmetic equals can be seen as an Equivalence relation between the left and right hand side. If the statement is sound, both belong to the same Equivalence class generated by =.

One might ask how we can tell if two Equivalence classes are equal, then. Through set equality, that is, we'd need to show that any member in A is a member in B and vice versa.

Comment: Equality is much more elementary then iso/homomorphism. Although it is a relationship, equality further differentiates between objects in the same equivalence classes. You can think of equivalence as generalized equality, but it's still not it. Equality is fundamental. That said, I just wanted to add this comment. +1 for the answer.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Yes, I agree that equality is more elementary - although I'm not sure where we usually pinpoint the first definition of equality - perhaps in set equality?

Comment: elemental equality, at least in Mathematical Logic.

Answer (score 0):

> Are all iPhones 8 structured molecularly the same?

There was a report a while ago about how Apple made its cases for some new iPhone model. The case was made from a top and a bottom part. Both parts with highest possible precision. But if you pick a top half and a bottom half at random, there will be a tiny difference in sizes.

So all half cases are measured, which can be done with higher precision than manufacturing. And then you pick two halves that are as closely together in size as possible, and this was said to make the mismatch smaller by a factor ten.

But this should answer your question: The cases, which should be identical, have measurably different sizes.

If we go smaller: Any two protons, any two neutrons, any two electrons are identical. Two atoms with the same number of protons, neutrons and electrons, and all electrons in matching orbits, are identical. (Due to quantum physics, electrons are not rotating around the nucleus, but have a probability distribution, which is the same for electrons in the same orbit). All in all there are a few hundred or maybe thousand different possible atoms if you consider how they could be distinguished.

Small molecules made from identical atoms can be different, because molecules are vibrating. Quantum physics have still enough effect that the number of possible vibration states is limited, especially for very small molecules. (As an observer you could ignore the vibration and claim the molecules are identical, but they are really not if their vibration is different.) You could probably calculate the number of possible states a molecule could be in, and that number will grow exponentially with the size of the molecule. At some size you could expect molecules that are unique in the universe.

For things built from molecules, they will be unique (not identical to any other thing in the universe) if the size is large enough.